# Unit Tesing - Mockito MyBatis throwing nullpointer exception for selectone returning boolean

Tags: java, unit-testing, mybatis

I'm using InjectMocks for DAo class and setting dependency using `@Mock`. The `@Before` and `@After` annotations used for setup method and called `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`. Here is my mockito Class:

```
public class DataDAOTest {

    @InjectMocks
    DataDAOImpl DataDAO;

    @Mock
    DateUtil dateUtil;

    @Mock
    ReferenceDataDAOImpl referenceDataDAOImpl;

    @Mock
    SqlSessionTemplate sqlSession;

    @Mock
    HashMap<String, Object> params;

    @BeforeMethod
    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsMemberExists_DateOffsetFlag_False_Success() {
        //Set Up
        BaseRequest request = new BaseRequest();
        request.setMemberId(11111111L);

        //Expectation
        when(wellnessProgramsDAO.isMemberExists(request)).thenReturn(true);

        //SUT
        boolean response = wellnessProgramsDAO.isMemberExists(request);

        //Verify
        Assert.assertEquals(response, true);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetMemberWellnessActivity_Success() {
        //Set UP
        String wellnessPgmCd = "07";
        BaseRequest request = new BaseRequest();
        request.setMemberId(11111111L);

        //Expectation
        when(wellnessProgramsDAO.getMemberWellnessActivity(request, wellnessPgmCd)).thenReturn(mockGetMemberWellnessActivity());

        //SUT
        List<MemberWellnessActivity> mwaList = wellnessProgramsDAO.getMemberWellnessActivity(request, wellnessPgmCd);

        //Verify
        assertNotNull(mwaList);
        Assert.assertEquals(2, mwaList.size());
        Assert.assertEquals("Exercise", mwaList.get(0).getWellActDescTxt());
        Assert.assertEquals("WeightLoss", mwaList.get(1).getWellActDescTxt());
    }

}
```

Here is method from DAO impl

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class DataDAOImpl extends SqlSessionDaoSupport implements
        DataDAO {
    @Autowired
    private DateUtil dateUtil;

    @Autowired
    private ReferenceDataDAO referenceDataDAO;

    private static final String CURRENT_DATE = "currentDate"; 
    private static final String CURRENT_YEAR = "currentYear"; 

    @Override
    public boolean isMemberExists(BaseRequest request) {
        LOGGER.debug("Calling DOA impl to get isMemberExists");
        HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("memberId", request.getMemberId());
        if(dateUtil.isDateOffsetFlag()) {
            Date date = referenceDataDAO.getClaimProcessDate();
            params.put(CURRENT_DATE, dateUtil.getCurrentSystemDateInDBFormat(date));
        } else {
            params.put(CURRENT_DATE, dateUtil.getCurrentSystemDateInDBFormat());
        }
        boolean isMemberVIP = getSqlSession().selectOne("wellnessPrograms.isMemberExists", params);
        LOGGER.debug("isMemberExists from DB "+isMemberVIP);
        return isMemberVIP;
    }

    public List<MemberWellnessActivity> getMemberWellnessActivity(
            BaseRequest request, String wellnessPgmCd) {
        LOGGER.debug("Calling DOA impl to get MemberWellnessActivity ");
        HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("memberId", request.getMemberId());
        params.put("wellnessPgmCd", wellnessPgmCd);
        if(dateUtil.isDateOffsetFlag()) {
            Date date = referenceDataDAO.getClaimProcessDate();
            params.put(CURRENT_YEAR, dateUtil.getCurrentYear(date));
        } else {
            params.put(CURRENT_YEAR, dateUtil.getCurrentYear());
        }
        List<MemberWellnessActivity> memberWellnessActivites = getSqlSession().selectList("wellnessPrograms.getMemberWellnessActivity", params);
        LOGGER.debug("Member Wellness Activites from DB "+memberWellnessActivites);
        return memberWellnessActivites;
    }

}
```

SQL from xml file

```
<select id="isMemberExists" resultType="boolean">
   <![CDATA[
    SELECT 
        (CASE WHEN (COUNT(MEMBER_ID)  > 0) 
            THEN '1' ELSE '0' END
        ) AS "IS_EXISTS" 
    FROM ${Schema}.MEMBER 
    WHERE MEMBER_ID=#{memberId} 
  ]]>
</select>
```

I'm getting null pointer exception while executing selectone. I have debugged code and session is available, not sure why I'm getting null pointer. Appreciate any help.
Note that test case for getMemberWellnessActivity method is working fine, only difference is selectList instead of selectOne

Comment: please provide the complete code of your TestCase

Comment: Do you mean there's an NPE inside the `selectOne` method?  Or do you mean on the line where you call it?  If it's the latter, it indicates that `getSqlSession()` is returning null.  In either case, you haven't really shown enough code for anyone to be able to tell you why.

Comment: I have given complete code.
While debugging, I checked getSqlSession() is returning session object. The issue is while executing selectOne("wellnessPrograms.isMemberExists", params); Not sure why getting nullpointe.

Answer (score 0):

added below mock on sqlSession befor calling DAO method and it worked like charm. Additionaly, I have run code thru TestNG and Cobertura code coverage and results are positive. Thank you all for your help.

```
public void testIsMemberExists_DateOffsetFlag_False_Success() {
    //Set Up
    BaseRequest request = new BaseRequest();
    request.setMemberId(11111111L);

    //Expectation
    when(sqlSession.selectOne(sql.capture(), paramsCaptor.capture())).thenReturn(new Boolean(true));
    when(wellnessProgramsDAO.isMemberExists(request)).thenReturn(true);

    //SUT
    boolean response = wellnessProgramsDAO.isMemberExists(request);

    //Verify
    Assert.assertEquals(response, true);
}
```